# Why am I getting: 'System.Collections.IEnumerable' has no type parameters and so cannot have type arguments?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, passwords, ienumerable, credentials

This is my simple username and password login which has the ability to redirect the user to a different 'members area' page.

However I get a:

BC32045: 'System.Collections.IEnumerable' has no type parameters and so cannot have type arguments

And I have no idea why.

Can anyone help?

Thanks, David.

```
Public Class MyPage
Inherits Page
Private Structure Cred
    Public Username As String
    Public Password As String
    Public RedirectUrl As String
    Public Sub New(un As String, pw As String, Optional ru As String = "/admin/default.aspx")
        Username = un
        Password = pw
        RedirectUrl = ru
    End Sub
End Structure

Private ReadOnly _credentials As IEnumerable(Of Cred) = New () {New Cred("userone", "passwordone"), New Cred("usertwo", "passwordtwo"), New Cred("userthree", "passwordthree", "/admin/custom.aspx")}

Public Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Dim user = _credentials.SingleOrDefault(Function(x) x.Username = UserName.Text AndAlso x.Password = Password.Text)
    If user IsNot Nothing Then
        Session("Admin") = True
        Response.Redirect(user.RedirectUrl)
    Else
        Session("Admin") = False
        LtlLogin.Text = "<p>Sorry, you have provided incorrect login details.</p>"
    End If
End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Where do you get it?

Comment: @TimSchmelter on this line: Private ReadOnly _credentials As IEnumerable(Of Cred) = New () {New Cred("userone", "passwordone"), New Cred("usertwo", "passwordtwo"), New Cred("userthree", "passwordthree", "/admin/custom.aspx")}

Comment: You're probably importing System.Collections rather than System.Collections.Generic somewhere.

Comment: The error is pretty clear, as @Craig indicates `IEnumerable<T>` resides in the namespace `System.Collections.Generic`. Your compiler error tells you it finds the type `System.Collections.IEnumerable`, which has no type arguments. You're missing `Imports System.Collections.Generic`.

Comment: @CraigH Thanks Craig, however all of this has just gone over my head... Any idea on how to restructure my code so it'll work? Thanks. David.

Comment: At the top of your code file put `Imports System.Collections.Generic`

Comment: @CraigH Hi Craig. I've added the above line but still the same error.

Comment: Try removing the `Imports` line you added and changing it to `Private ReadOnly _credentials As System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable(Of Cred)`...

Comment: @CraigH Thanks Craig! Now, I get a 'type expected'. I've removed the New() too but then I get: BC30679: Array initializers are valid only for arrays, but the type of '_credentials' is 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable(Of ASP.hub_lv2_aspx.MyPage.Cred)'.

Comment: @CraigH If you change it to
 = New Cred {...} 
I get:  '_credentials' is already declared as 'Private ReadOnly Dim _credentials As System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable(Of Cred)' in this class.

Comment: This should work according to my little test: `Private ReadOnly _credentials As System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable(Of Cred) = {New Cred("userone", "passwordone"), New Cred("usertwo", "passwordtwo"), New Cred("userthree", "passwordthree", "/admin/custom.aspx")}`

Comment: @CraigH I rally appreciate your help here Craig, however, I now get the following: BC30679: Array initializers are valid only for arrays, but the type of '_credentials' is 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable(Of ASP.login_aspx.MyPage.Cred)'. No idea how to even attempt to understand that. Thanks once more!

Answer (score 0):

I get "type expected" compiler error which is correct. Either remove the `New()`, so replace

```
Private ReadOnly _credentials As IEnumerable(Of Cred) = New () {New Cred("userone", "passwordone"), New Cred("usertwo", "passwordtwo"), New Cred("userthree", "passwordthree", "/admin/custom.aspx")}
```

with

```
Private ReadOnly _credentials As IEnumerable(Of Cred) =  {New Cred("userone", "passwordone"), New Cred("usertwo", "passwordtwo"), New Cred("userthree", "passwordthree", "/admin/custom.aspx")}
```

or use `New Cred(){...}`

However, you should use a class instead of a struct. With `Option Strict` you can't use `If user IsNot Nothing` since `Cred` is a `Structure`, hence a value type.

Comment: Thanks mate, however, I still get the same error message Tim. Any ideas why? Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: @d.c: have you tried to reopen visual studio and to recompile the project? The compiler error seems to be incorrect with the current code.

Comment: I use DreamWeaver, and upon refresh it just displays the same error message. P.s. Please don't kill me because I use DreamWeaver :)